# Token Not Valid error when performing SQL calculation

Tags: php, sql, ibm-midrange

I'm attempting to run the following SQL statement, but I can't quite get it right.

This is what works on the iSeries within STRSQL, and also works within my PHP program. But I don't see the `(mbmrxl * mbndtr)` result as I do on the iSeries.
That column is blank.

```
SELECT SURNME, ODLBNM, ODOBNM, MBMXRL, MBNRCD, MBNDTR, (mbmxrl * mbndtr), objrnk 
FROM mytable WHERE surnme = 'STP_ROLL' ORDER BY (mbmxrl * mbndtr) desc
```

I need to perform this calculation and place it in a new field called `TOTRANK`:
    MBMRXL * MBNDTR

This is the php query I'm trying:

```
$query = "SELECT SURNME, ODLBNM, ODOBNM, MBMXRL, MBNRCD, MBNDTR, TOTRANK, objrnk FROM (select mbmrxl * mbndtr as TOTRANK, from mytable) 
WHERE surnme = 'STP_ROLL' ORDER BY TOTRANK desc";
```

When run the above code, I get this message:

> SQL statement failed Token . was not valid. Valid tokens: , FROM INTO.
>   SQLCODE=-104

How do I debug this?

Comment: A subquery in a FROM must have an alias.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SURNME, ODLBNM, ODOBNM, MBMXRL, MBNRCD, MBNDTR, objrnk
, mbmrxl * mbndtr as TOTRANK
FROM  mytable  
WHERE surnme = 'STP_ROLL' 
ORDER BY mbmrxl * mbndtr desc
```

Your SQL select statement should be changed to the above.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. 
I also notice a typo.  mbmrxl should be mbmxrl.

Barry